# PHP: Save 'dynamic text or pdf content' in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

**runtime: php**

**GCS file uploading process:**

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$file = fopen($source, 'r');
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload($file, [
  'name' => $objectName
]);
```

Now i want to create object with dynamic text/pdf instead of using `$source` path file.

for example:

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$objectName = "newfile.txt";
$content = "This is the dynamic content";
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload($content, [
    'name' => 'textDocs/'.$objectName
]);
```

so it'll create new object as "newfile.txt" with content "This is the dynamic content".

is there any cloud libraries or functions to process this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***For Dynamic creation of text document (with-dynamic-content) in Google-cloud-storage, below code will be work perfectly.***

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$objectName = "newfile.txt";                  // name of object/text-file
$content = "This is the dynamic content";     // assign static/dynamic data to $content variable
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->upload($content, [
    'name' => 'textDocs/'.$objectName
]);
```

***For Dynamic creation of pdf document (with-dynamic-content) in Google-cloud-storage.***

```
$name = "samplePDF.pdf";
$p = new PDFTable("L");
$p->AddPage();
$p->setfont('helvetica','',12);
$p->htmltable($html);
$pdfData = $p->output("",'S'); // returns pdf as string
$filename = "pdfDocs/".$name;
/** 
 * file uploading into google cloud storage : start
 */
$storage->bucket($bucketName, true)->upload(
    $pdfData,
    [
    'name' => $filename,
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]
);
/** 
 * file uploading into google cloud storage : end
 */
$p->output($name,"D"); // D->downloads file in our system.
```